# Modifying query to use a new table in place of a static range of numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a working query (shown below) that I'm trying to consolidate and use another table for a more direct approach but I'm not quite sure how to go about this.

First, Here's the query:

```
select
case 
when callingpartyno       in (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
  then callingpartyno
when finallycalledpartyno in (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
  then finallycalledpartyno
end as id
, sum(duration) as total_talk_time_seconds
, round(sum(duration) / 60,2) as total_talk_time_minutes
, sum(if(legtype1 = 1,1,0)) as total_outbound
, sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 1) as total_inbound
, sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 0) as total_missed
, sum(if(legtype1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
  sum(if(legtype1 = 2, 1, 0))  as total_calls
, now() as time_of_report
, curdate() as date_of_report
from 
  ambition.session a
  join ambition.callsummary b
    on a.notablecallid = b.notablecallid
where 
date(b.ts) >= curdate()
 and (
callingpartyno in (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312
)
 or  finallycalledpartyno in (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312
 )
)
group by
id;
```

Instead of looking for `callingpartyno and finallycalledpartyno` in that range of 16 numbers, I made a table called `users` that houses the 4-digit extensions and the first/last name of the agents. I want to join that table and use it to display the names and extensions of the users instead.

The table structure is:

```
ambition.users
   ID PK NN INT
   extension INT
   firstn  varchar
   lastn varchar
```

So I basically want to change my query to say "When callingpartyno/finallycalledpartyno in u.extension" etc.

Which type of joing would I need to do to match what I have in the existing query, and how would I structure it to keep the results the same just using a new table instead of a range?

Comment: Invalid group by. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: no need to join. Use subquery instead: `where 
date(b.ts) >= curdate()
 and 
callingpartyno in (select distinct extension from ambition.users)`....same goes for `finallycalledpartyno`.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but how would I select first_name, last_name and extension from ambition.users in my initial select statement without joining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect something like this:

```
select uc.agent as calling_agent, uf.agent as final_agent,
       sum(duration) as total_talk_time_seconds,
       round(sum(duration) / 60, 2) as total_talk_time_minutes,
       sum(legtype1 = 1) as total_outbound,
       sum(legtype1 = 2 and answered = 1) as total_inbound,
       sum(legtype1 = 2 and answered = 0) as total_missed,
       sum(legtype1 = 1) +                   -- outbound calls
       sum(legtype1 = 2)  as total_calls,
       now() as time_of_report,
       curdate() as date_of_report
from ambition.session s join
     ambition.callsummary cs
     on s.notablecallid = cs.notablecallid left join
     users uc
     on ?.callingpartyno = uc.extension left join
     users uf
     on ?.finallycalledpartyno = uf.extension
where date(b.ts) >= curdate() and
      (uc.extension is not null or uf.extension is not null)
group by calling_agent, final_agent;
```

The `?` are for the names of the corresponding tables and columns.